# Remove n last character from a string

Tags: r, string, gsub

I would like to remove the third and fourth last character from as string.

Here is some sample data:

```
HS0202
HS0902
MV0100
SUE0300
```

I would need return something like this

```
HS02
HS02
MV00
SUE00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract from first to fourth last characters, and paste on the final character as follows:

```
have <- c('HS0202', 'HS0902', 'MV0100', 'SUE0300')

want <- paste0(substring(have,1,nchar(have)-3),substring(have,nchar(have)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a regex with `gsub()`:

```
gsub("..(?=..$)", "", chrs, perl = TRUE)
# "HS02"  "HS02"  "MV00"  "SUE00"
```

Or with `stringr::str_remove()`:

```
library(stringr)

str_remove(chrs, "..(?=..$)")
# "HS02"  "HS02"  "MV00"  "SUE00"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)

stri_sub_replace(x, from = -4, to = -3, value = "")

[1] "HS02"  "HS02"  "MV00"  "SUE00"
```

Or with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

str_sub(x, start = -4, end = -3) <- ""
```

**Data**

```
x <- c("HS0202", "HS0902", "MV0100", "SUE0300")
```